# Default vhost name changing between restarts

Tags: apache

I can't figure out why my default vhost servername is randomly changing between restarts of httpd.

I have a RHEL8 server that has mod_ssl installed and the ssl.conf file is loading.  I have made no changes to it.  It defines the `_default_:443` vhost and when I run `httpd -S` it is showing different names getting assigned to the default and the first vhost, both of which point to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:40`.

The problem is that the name sometimes overlaps with my locally configured vhost's ServerName.  And thus, the default vhost is getting picked and not mine.  I can't figure out where httpd is getting the hostname from because neither of them match what I've set the hostname to be using `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname <my-host>`.